# K-means clustering multiple dimensions

Tags: c#, k-means

I'm working on the K-means clustering algorithm. There are alot of examples available, but I can't find an example that explains what I'm trying to do.

My dataset contains customers and their purchases. Every 1 in the dataset means the customer bought this item. A 0 means not bought.

```
0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1
1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0
1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
```

Left to right represent the different items.
Top to bottom represent the customers. I want to cluster the customers. So there are 4 dimensions in the dataset and there will be 10 points.

Now I'm trying to create points from this dataset for the next steps. I want to create a list containing all point object and then assign them to the right clusters, but I don't know how to handle the 4 different dimensions when I create a point object.

```
class Point
{
    public int ClusterNumber { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Point(int clusterNumber, int CustomerId, int ProductId)
    {
        ClusterNumber = clusterNumber;
        X = CustomerId;
        Y = ProductId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to cluster the customers or do you want to cluster the items? And how many clusters do you want to build?

Comment: Using `X` and `Y` as actual point coordinates based on the customer ID and product ID doesn't make any sense. It would suggest that you can "order" these points or "arrange" them, but customer ID=4 isn't "closer" to a point than customer ID=7 (same goes for items).

Comment: @Progman I want to cluster the customers. So I get 10 points. The amount of clusters doesnt really matter. Can be 1,2 or more. Yes, you are right but how should I order them. The multiple dimension part makes me confused

Comment: By what metric do you want to cluster the customers? Why should customer with id=4, 7 and 8 be clustered together and customer with id=2 in another cluster (of total two clusters, as an example)? To be more specific: What is the 'distance' between a customer and the cluster point?

Comment: The customers that buy the same products get clustered in the same cluster. (The dataset specified is a part of the total set)

Answer (score 1):

A point in this specific k-means problem is the set of products a customer bought. You have four customers with their list of bought items, so it would be something like this:

```
public class CustomerPoint
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public ISet<int> ProductIds { get; set; }
}
```

Then the cluster point would be some abstract point (not as in the `abstract` c# keyword) like this:

```
public class ClusterPoint
{
    public int ClusterNumber { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<int, float> ProductWeights { get; set; }
}
```

The `ProductWeights` will be a dictionary which maps the CustomerId to a value between 0 and 1 (both including), which indicates that this product has been bought or not. The distance between the `ClusterPoint` and the `CustomerPoint` will be the difference between the product weight and the fact that the customer bought the item or not. The "distance" will be calculated for all products and the sum of these distances results in the total distance you have to minimize. When you have two cluster points `CLP(0.4, 0.1, 0.8, 0.5)` and `CLP(0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9)` and you have a customer `CUP(0, 1, 1, 0)` the differences will be as follow:

```
CLP1:
    |0 - 0.4|² = 0.16
    |1 - 0.1|² = 0.81
    |1 - 0.8|² = 0.04
    |0 - 0.5|² = 0.25
               ------
                 1.26
CLP2:
    |0 - 0.2|² = 0.04
    |1 - 0.7|² = 0.09
    |1 - 0.9|² = 0.01
    |0 - 0.9|² = 0.81
               ------
                 0.95
```

So the customer is "closer" to the second cluster point, so it gets assigned to that one.

Maybe you can change the `CustomerPoint.ProductIds` property to a `IDictionary<int, float>` value as well and use the values `1` and `0` for  "bought the item" or not. But that's implementation detail.